# Windows 10 login information for accessing samba share protected directory located on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, login, samba, windows-10

Can someone give an example of login information (username and password) on Windows 10 for the samba protected directory which is located on Ubuntu 18.04?

I have created a user in Ubuntu and added `smbpasswd` for him, but I don't know how the username should look to be able to get into the protected directory.

[image: Enter network credenitals in Win 10]

[image: Error]

Accessing a public directory from Windows is working without a problem.

Comment: Since the answer seems to be too obvious I'm assuming you get an error when you enter the username and smbpasswd password you created in Ubuntu. What is the path to the "Protected" folder on the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Ubuntu path for that directory is `/samba/Protected`. I made it like [this](https://websiteforstudents.com/samba-setup-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-with-windows-systems/) setup here.

Comment: Does the new user you created on the ubuntu machine have the same username as the one on the Windows client?

Comment: No, it doesn't have the same name. Now I have created ubuntu user with the same name as windows user but still can get to the protected directory.

Comment: Same password as the Windows user's login password?

Comment: Yes, also the same password.

Comment: Last question: When you first installed WIn10 did you log into it with a Microsoft Account - xxx@yyy.com type of thing.

Comment: No, I didn't log in with MS account.

Comment: Took a test machine, followed your linked HowTo, and given your answers above I cannot reproduce your symptoms. My suggestion is the next time you reboot that Win10 machine access the Protected share first then the Public one - not the other way around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As for this specific error message:

> Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user,
>   using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all
>   previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

The problem here is that when a user on Windows first makes contact with a server it automatically passes that users' local login username. If you have a public share it remembers that it took that username successfully. When you try to connect to a private share and don't pass the exact same username and password, it thinks you are trying to access with another name.

Some workarounds:

**1) Map the Windows user to the local Linux user** - this is useful for Win10 users who log into their systems with a Microsoft account.

- Create a file at `/etc/samba/smbusers`
- Map the local Linux user to the Windows user by adding the conversion to the file. For example:

```
luci = luci@example.com
john = "John Smith"
```

- Then add a reference to the map in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` in the `[global]` section:

```
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
```

- Finally restart smbd: `sudo service smbd restart`

**2) Make another connection to the Linux server**

Windows can address a Linux server in two (three in Win10) different ways. By hostname, by ip address, or by mDNS name (Win10 only):

```
\\ubuntu\Protected
\\192.168.0.100\Protected
\\ubuntu.local\Protected
```

Even though all of these point to the same machine, Windows sees them a three separate hosts.

**3) Map the "network drive"**

When mapping a drive, select the "connect using different credentials" option.

Comment: Solved. True, on the first contact, it passes users local login user name. I tried with approach [2] and [3]. Both approaches are working. For credentials I used username of user that I created with `sudo adduser zombie` in Ubuntu and password generated for that user with `sudo smbpasswd -a zombie`.